# Time Manager runs with different speed in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, timemanager

I created a map to show my data with time manager. The feature type is polygon. 
Changes in "Show frame for x milliseconds" affect the time the frames are shown. But the first frame is shown for x milliseconds and the next frames are shown for much less milliseconds. It almost seems it needs to much time to render and then it runs through the frames.
When I export and generate a GIF. That works fine.
Are there any settings I can change to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes TimeManager animations run faster than specified. In this case, it usually helps to stop and restart the animation a few times. The cause of this behavior is unknown.

If the animation runs slower than specified, this may be caused by longer rendering times. Renderings times of successive frames may speed up since parts of the map may be cached.